# EPPlus: bug combining shapes and programmatic pictures

Tags: epplus

**Problem:**

When I programatically open an Excel file that has shapes in it (eg. arrows), and then I modify this file by adding a new image to it (programatically), if I try to get the bytes (`GetAsByteArray`) of this new modified Excel file, it crashes.

**Steps to reproduce bug:**

1. Create an Excel file (xlsx) and add a shape in it (eg. an arrow)
2. Use this code to open that file and add a programmatic picture

   ```
   string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/input.xlsx");

   using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
   {
       // Read file
       ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream);

       // Get worksheets
       ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();

       // Add programmatic picture
       worksheet.Drawings
           .AddPicture("logo", new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/logo.png")))
           .SetPosition(5, 0, 5, 0);

       byte[] output = File(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "output.xlsx");
   }
   ```

Any ideas or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will give you the bytes after adding an image. But nothing else will happen to the Excel file.

```
//create a fileinfo object of an excel file on the disk
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(""~/Content/input.xlsx"));

//create a new Excel package from the file
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    //create an instance of the the first sheet in the loaded file
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

    //Add programmatic picture
    worksheet.Drawings
        .AddPicture("logo", new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/logo.png")))
        .SetPosition(5, 0, 5, 0);

    //get the new size in byte array
    byte[] output = package.GetAsByteArray();
}
```